Quitar espacio en blanco en datatable
tengo el siguiente datatable
function _buildTable(data) {
var arraystore = new DevExpress.data.ArrayStore({
    key: "folioRol",
    data: data
});
let arg = {
    selector: $Table,
    data: arraystore,
    columns: _columns,
    rowAlternationEnabled: true,
    export: false, //Exporta excel
    busqueda: true, //Buscar
    filterRow: true, //buscar por columna
    editColumn: false, //Poder cambiar de lugar,mostrar y ocultar columnas
    loadPanel: false, // al cargar el grid no muestro el loadin propio
    onCellHoverChanged: function (e) {
        if ((e.rowType === "data" || e.rowType === "header" || e.rowType === "filter") && e.column.dataField !== "Action") {
            if (e.eventType == 'mouseover') {
                if (iniciarTimer == true) {
                    iniciarTimer = false;
                    //if (interval == null)
                    //    _starTimeoutSecund();
                }
            }
        } else if ((e.rowType === "header" || e.rowType === "filter") && e.column.dataField === "Action") {
            if (e.eventType == 'mouseover') {
                if (iniciarTimer == true) {
                    iniciarTimer = false;
                    //if (interval == null)
                    //    _starTimeoutSecund();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
dataGridEx.Fill(arg);

}
el cual me carga sin problemas mi tabla, el problema que tengo es que si tiene pocos resultados o ir a la última página deja mucho espacio en blanco, como le puedo hacer para que tome el tamaño de los resultados.


Debes agregarle a las propiedades de inicialización height con valor 'auto' esto permite que de forma automatica la altura de a tabla se ajuste.
otra forma seria calcularlo:
onContentReady: function(e) {
    adjustGridHeight(e.component);
},

y el metodo:
function adjustGridHeight(grid) {
    // Obtener el número de filas visibles
    let visibleRowCount = grid.getVisibleRows().length;
    
    // Ajustar la altura del contenedor del DataGrid
    let rowHeight = 30; // Establece la altura de fila estimada, ajusta según tu diseño
    let minHeight = 100; // Altura mínima para evitar que se colapse completamente
    
    let calculatedHeight = Math.max(visibleRowCount * rowHeight, minHeight);
    
    $(grid.element()).parent().height(calculatedHeight);
}

